# How can you add "." as a resource-root to a module using jboss-cli?

Tags: jboss, jboss-cli

Not sure there's a way to do what I want with jboss-cli, so looking for confirmation.

If I connect to EAP using jboss-cli and run this command to add a module:

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] module add --name="test" --resources="."
Failed to locate C:\EAP-6.4.0\bin\"."
```

The module add command *should* create a module.xml with the following element:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="test">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="."/>
    </resources>

<dependencies>
```

According to module add --help, it looks like the command expects a physical resource to copy into the directory where module.xml is created:

```
 --resources     - (used with add, required unless module-xml is used) a list of
               filesystem paths (usually jar files) separated by a
               filesystem-specific path separator, i.e.
               java.io.File.pathSeparatorChar. The file(s) specified will be
               copied to the created module's directory.
```

The description seems to match the behaviour, so just looking for confirmation that there isn't a "jboss-cli" way, before resorting to sed.

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't look like that is possible to do with CLI. You can file a request for enhancement here if you'd like https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE.

Answer (score 1):

On JBoss EAP 7.2 (and likely on other versions of JBoss too), it is possible to do this by creating the module.xml file in advance and using "module add" with the --module-xml option to explicitly specify the module.xml file.

Here is an example which creates a module consisting of a single properties file, creates the module.xml file, and then adds the module to JBoss:

```
% mkdir /tmp/module-src
% cd /tmp/module-src
% echo hello=bonjour > example.properties
% cat > module.xml
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="test">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="."/>
  </resources>
<dependencies>

% jboss-cli.sh --command="module add --resources=example.properties --module-xml=module.xml --name=test"
```

This creates the module directory, copies the module file (with resource-root path=".") into the module directory, and copies the specified resource(s) into the module directory.